# SELECT ID from 4 Tables SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, select

Have 4 tables like in image (Tables name are: Job, Home, Games, Example) there is no **persons** sorry for the error

[image]

I would like to SELECT only the ones with **ID=0**, so my output would be

output

```
Jean
Robocop
Witcher
Example1
```

this is my code so far

```
SELECT Job.name, Home.name, Games.name, Example.name 
FROM Job, Home, Games, Example 
WHERE ID=0
```

Comment: search for 'inner join' and 'left join'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL select:

```
SELECT name
FROM Job
WHERE ID=0
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM  Home 
WHERE ID=0
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM Games
WHERE ID=0
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM Example 
WHERE ID=0
```